# Zoom at a certain distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I have the following Unity Script

```
void Update()
{
    Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();

    if(Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out hit))
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraController>().ZoomIn(hit.transform.position);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the camera I Have

```
public void ZoomIn(Vector3 target)
{
    zoomSavePosition = camera.transform.position;
    StartCoroutine(Zoom(zoomSavePosition, target, zoomDuration));
}


// ZoomRoutine
IEnumerator Zoom(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, float duration)
{
    float time = 0;
    Quaternion rotation = camera.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(to - camera.transform.position);
    while (time < zoomDuration)
    {
        camera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, time / zoomDuration);
        camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rotation, targetRotation, time / zoomDuration);

        time += TimeManager.instance.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    camera.transform.position = to;
    camera.transform.rotation = targetRotation;
}
```

This works great, but it zoom inside the object. I would like to, no matter from where and to what, I always zoom and end up at the same distance of the target.

I was thinking to use `MoveTowards` but inside the coroutine this will make the movement stop, but the rotation will keep going (and it's a big ugly)

So give a point A and a point B how do I calculate a distance in the middle that is set to always the same distance from B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For zooming to a specific distance from the target object you need to calculate the distance from the target object in direction of the camera and then subtract it to the target position.

```
var heading = to - from;
var dist = heading.magnitude;
var direction = heading / dist;

Vector3 newTargetPosition = to - (direction * distance);
```

Ref: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DirectionDistanceFromOneObjectToAnother.html

With this adjustment you can stop zooming to any provided distance. 
Here is how adjusted code would look like:

```
public void ZoomIn(Vector3 target)
{
    float targetDistance = 2f;
    zoomSavePosition = camera.transform.position;
    StartCoroutine(Zoom(zoomSavePosition, target, zoomDuration, targetDistance));
}


// ZoomRoutine
IEnumerator Zoom(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, float duration, float distance)
{
    float time = 0;
    Quaternion rotation = camera.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(to - camera.transform.position);

    var heading = to - from;
    var dist = heading.magnitude;
    var direction = heading / dist;

    Vector3 newTargetPosition = to - (direction * distance);

    while (time < zoomDuration)
    {
        camera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(from, newTargetPosition, time / zoomDuration);
        camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rotation, targetRotation, time / zoomDuration);

        time += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    camera.transform.position = newTargetPosition;
    camera.transform.rotation = targetRotation;
}
```

You can set value of targetDistance where you want to stop zooming.